# User RegEx to (un)match all words length above a specific value

Tags: java, regex, string, token

Question on Java RegEx:

I have a tokenizer where i want to return only tokens that have length **above** a certain length.

For example: 
I need to return all tokens that are more than 1 char in this text:
*"This is a text ."*

I need to get 3 tokens: *"This"*, *"is"*, *"text"*
The following tokens are not needed: *"a"* and *"."*.
Notice that the string can have any character (not only alpha-bet chars)

I tried this code but i am not sure how to complete it:

```
    String lines[]  = {"This is o n e l e tt e r $ % ! sentence"};


    for(String line : lines)
    {
        String orig = line;

        Pattern Whitespace = Pattern.compile("[\\s\\p{Zs}]+");
        line = Whitespace.matcher(orig).replaceAll(" ").trim();
        System.out.println("Test:\t'" + line + "'");

        Pattern SingleWord = Pattern.compile(".+{1}");  //HOW CAN I DO IT?
        SingleWord.matcher(line).replaceAll(" ").trim();
        System.out.println("Test:\t'" + line + "'");



    }
```

Thanks

Comment: In your example why the dot is seperated from "text" ? There is no space in between

Comment: What about `tt`? See http://ideone.com/blZvnJ

Comment: thanks Wiktor... what does p means?
Can you post your answer with some more explanation please?

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: in fact there are few good answers below , this is one of them
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you don't use `\w{2,}` like this :

```
String line = "This is o n e l e tt e r $ % ! sentence";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w{2,}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
This
is
tt
sentence
```

---

**Edit**

Then you could use this `[A-Za-z0-9_@.-]{2,}` you can specify your special character that you don't want to avoid, or you can use `[^\s]{2,}` or `\S{2,}` [a non-whitespace character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

**Inputs**

```
This is o email@gmail.com n e l e tt e r $ % ! sentence
```

**Output**

```
This
is
email@gmail.com
tt
sentence
```

Comment: because i need charachters that are not alpha-bet
For example if there is a string including email then i need to get the email as single token eventually

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java 8 you can do it this way :

```
String line = "This is o n e l e tt e r $ % ! sentence";
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")));
array.removeIf(u -> u.length() == 1);
```

**`array` now contains :**

```
This
is
tt
sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use something simple like

```
List<String> words = new LinkedList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\S{2,}").matcher(line);
while(m.find())
{
    words.add(m.group(0));
}
```

The `\\S` (with an uppercase 's') matches all non-space characters.

Disclaimer: I haven't run this, but it should work (maybe with some minimal alterations)